# Create a line graph in HTML from local CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, graph

I need to make an script that will automatically load data from an .CSV file (that is automatically generated on a shared drive) and make a line graph that will be displayed on a TV here in our office. I will automate the script to run every morning with a Jenkins job.

So far I tried to apply this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OK4TJfCzdY but it uses a  local webserver to host the files, and this is not posbile for me to apply.

This should probably work with HTML & JavaScript.

Any ideas what tools or libraries should I to use ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a HTML and JavaScript solution, with the data file being in a known location on your network, you could look into D3.js (or any number of other charting solutions).

As an example, check out the following line chart tutorial in D3: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

Comment: This looks helpful ! Thanks !